# Piping parameter issue with powershell

Tags: powershell

I ran into a weird issue that I do not know how to explain. I hope someone could shed some light for me.

I would like to create a function which takes a parameter of an array, let's say $scriptnames and users have an option to pipe it from previous results should they prefer. I stripped away the unrelated stuff to better illustrate my confusion.

In the process of the module, I read each item from the array and just print the item.

**My function:**

```
function Get-Test
{
 [CmdletBinding()]
 param
 (
 [parameter(mandatory=$true,
             ValueFromPipeline=$True,
             ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
  [string[]]$scriptNames
  )
  BEGIN
  {
  }
  PROCESS
  {
    foreach ($scriptName in $scriptNames)
    {
        Write-Verbose "Executing: $scriptname" 
    }    
  }
  END{}
```

Here was what confused me:

**Scenario 1:**

I used this command to get the list of the file in my directory:

```
get-childitem | Select-Object {$_.BaseName}
```

The list of file was return correctly without extension:

[image]

However, when I piped the results to my function, I got this print out:

[image]

Notice the unwanted $_.BaseName= literal was added.

**Scenario 2:**

However, if I issue this command:

```
get-childitem | Select-Object $_.BaseName
```

The results did not really filter out the basename only

[image]

but when piping to my function:

```
get-childitem | Select-Object $_.BaseName|
Get-Test -Verbose
```

the $_basename literal was not included:

[image]

However, the basename included the extension, which really confused me.

**Can someone see something flaring up at you? and why did the following things happen**:

1) Why was $_.BaseName literal tagged in the print out in scenario 1, which I did not ask for?

2) Why the select did not seem to work in scenario 2, but the print-out did not have $_.baseName with the exact same script?

3) What do I need to correct in my script to print out the filename only without the extension and without the literal $_.BaseName?

Comment: `Select-Object {$_.BaseName}` -> `ForEach-Object {$_.BaseName}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you include `Select-Object BaseName`, your returning an array of objects with 1 property, `BaseName`. Switch it to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName` to do what you're looking for, or you can use `(Get-ChildItem).BaseName` to achieve the same result.

Whenever you see something expected as a string (i.e. `Filename`) that's instead returned as an object/hashtable (i.e. `@{$_.BaseName=Filename}`). If you want to have it return the extension as well, use `Name` instead of `BaseName`. If you want the full path to the file, use `FullName` in that case.

To answer your scenario questions...

1. That behaved as expected, as you only specified a single property to be returned from the objects, but are still returning objects. The object property is named `$_.BaseName` because you defined it that way with how you called it (usually you would just need to specify the property name without including the `$_.` in front to indicate the pipeline object, i.e. `Select-Object BaseName`). It's also working because of the surrounding curly braces in Scenario 1
2. The verbose text appears to be defaulting to the Name property, even though you're passing full objects to it. The first example in Scenario 2 returns the full object since you're calling Select-Object incorrectly.
3. My initial answer should cover the solution, I think

Comment: Awesome! That explains it!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify how you are calling your function, so cannot really tell what's wrong with #1, it seems like you are returning an array instead of string

#2 is easy. You should have simply wrote

```
gci |select-object basename
```

instead of $_.basename.

#3 Probably related to 2.

Also, do not use Select-Object if you are trying to get Basename and do not want the header. You can instead do:

```
(get-childitem).basename | whatever
```

Here is how it prints with the example function you provided above

```
PS C:\> (gci).basename |get-test -ver
VERBOSE: Executing: batch
VERBOSE: Executing: DB
VERBOSE: Executing: Modules
VERBOSE: Executing: nix
VERBOSE: Executing: py
VERBOSE: Executing: utils
VERBOSE: Executing: Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile
VERBOSE: Executing: Microsoft.PowerShell_profile
VERBOSE: Executing: PowerShellTranscripts
```

Oh you really should remove Mandatory, if you are expecting to pipe stuff to it or you will get a binding error:

```
Get-Test : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'scriptNames' because it is an empty string
```

Comment: I created it as a Module, put it in the place where module is supposed to be put and recognized by PS, then I use Import-Module to load the module. I also tried to load it using . .\myFunction.ps1 and it is still having the same behavior. I think the issue might reside in the script and not how the script was loaded. But, I am new to PS, so I might be doing something that I do not suppose to do.

Comment: I tried using basename instead of $_.basename and it is still doing the same thing...weird..

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I was referring to the "line" where you call you function. What is that line? Select-Object {$_.BaseName}| your_func ?. In any case, you should not be using {$_.baseline } or $_.baseline. Use the last line I mentioned aboe and put your function name insteadof 'whatever'. See if that helps with the error